# How can I fix an icon onto the right hand side of a Row?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: Flutter Card]

I am using a Card widget populated with a Row. At the end of the row I use a GFIconButton widget which is the bin and it currently moves depending on the length of the menu item's name. I want the bin to stay at the far right position no matter what the length of the menu item is.

I am already using Alignment.centerRight

```
                Card(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10), //EdgeInsets.all(10),
          color: Colors.white,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
          ),
          child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                ClipRect(
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  widthFactor: 0.8,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(itemImg),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 70,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                )),
                const SizedBox(width: 30),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      name,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      "R$price",
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text(
                      variety,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                // Container(child: ),
                const SizedBox(width: 30),
                Text("x" + quantity.toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end),
                const SizedBox(width: 20),

                GFIconButton(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    //If points are above 0 a reward

                    //Id hard coded
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.delete_outline,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  ),
                  type: GFButtonType.transparent,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
```

Comment: could you include your code too?

Comment: please add your full code of card

Comment: and what package do you use for GFIconButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution:

```
Card(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('image'),
                        Text("texts cdppdwpwdpwdpolumn"),
                        Text('quantity'),
                        Expanded(child: SizedBox()), //this is crucial- this keeps icon always at the end
                        Icon(Icons.delete)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put Spacer between your quantity text widget and icon widget to align your icon widget to far right. For further information you need to include your code to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Either add a relative space between icon and the text or, wrap the icon on the right and everything on the left inside another row and use mainAxisAlignment as spaceBetween

Answer (score 0):

Change your last widgets in row to this:

```
Expanded(
                    child: Text("x" + quantity.toString(),
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                    child: GFIconButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        //If points are above 0 a reward

                        //Id hard coded
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.delete_outline,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                      ),
                      type: GFButtonType.transparent,
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Wrapping your icon with expanded widget is wrong, you should wrap your text with that, because if your text would be long and wrap your icon with expanded the icon would disappear. @Stamp777

Answer (score -1):

mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.SpaceBetween
and check if icon width and set it around 30

Comment: SpaceBetween modifier would affect all the items in the row. So it wouldn't be a viable solution when picture, text and quantity had different sizes. It would be inconsistent and result in a messy UI all across list of item cards.